# Getting in game name from UID

Tags: python, api, mobile, pubg

I've researched a lot about this but can't find a solution. Basically am building an app where a player is asked to enter his/her IGN (In game name) but it's difficult to copy it correctly because of designer fonts, so what I want is just let them enter their UID (Unique ID) and their IGN automatically pops up. I've seen this feature in many websites and apps like codashop.com, gameskharido.in, game.tv, etc.

Is there any API for this am unaware of or how is this possible?

Also, what I've noticed is
https://shop.garena.sg/app/100067/idlogin is the official top-up store by garena and https://gameskharido.in/app/100067/idlogin is one of many other sites. But notice that both these sites have same user interface and even their URL is similar which means somehow they are using same mechanism.
I really want this feature, please give your options down below. Thanks!

**Note** : This is only applicable for mobile games like PUBG, Call of Duty Mobile, Free fire, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function Login($game_id = null){
    if (is_null($game_id)) return false;
    $result = $this->request("POST", "https://shop.garena.sg/api/auth/player_id_login", array(
        "app_id" => 100067,
        "login_id" => strval($game_id)
    ));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt: add the imports, the call, the errors. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now this is working for me as well but the problem is, it's sometimes asking for captcha and the error continues to occur till I actually open my browser and solve that captcha by going to there website, also I tried using proxies but still it's not working sometimes.

Comment: Also what I noticed is, there API is sending request to there .js script which is returning the response, I noticed these scripts in Initiator tab in inspect, these scripts are as follows https://shop.garena.sg/assets/client.72393b7912a19ae1d3bf.js and https://shop.garena.sg/assets/vendor.72393b7912a19ae1d3bf.js so is there any way to directly send request to these and get a response?